# Who were John Connor's children and why were they special?

Tags: terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines, terminator-salvation

In Terminator 3 John and Kate are told that their kids are important.

> **T-800:** *Through her, you contact remnants of the military and learn how to fight Skynet, forming the core of the Resistance. Later, your children will become important.*

and in Terminator Salvation we see that Kate is pregnant.

**Who are John's kids are and why are they so important?**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you want to know how many children they have or why they are important.  You should only have 1 question.

Comment: @DavidW - I'm pretty sure a decent answer to either question would address both elements (e.g. "*they had seventeen kids and the fourteenth went on to become king of the world"*)

Answer (score 2):

In the Terminator Salvation timeline, John and Kate went on, according to *[Terminator Salvation: The Final Battle #12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_Salvation:_The_Final_Battle)*, to have two children, an unnamed son and a daughter named Sarah (after her grandmother).

[image]

Given that both were too young to have played any part in the Resistance movement, their future importance was probably as leaders of the tattered remains of the human race.